# Erro ao executar 'build_runner' acontece um 'Loop infinito no momento da construção'

Tags: flutter, build, packages

Adicionei os seguintes pacotes e versões `build_runner: ^1.10.2` e `mobx_codegen: ^1.1.0+1` no arquivo `pubspec.yaml` do meu projeto *Flutter* e no momento da geração do código automático obtive o seguinte 'looping' de **'erro/mensagem'**:

```
...
[INFO] 31m 49s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 31m 50s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 31m 51s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 31m 53s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[INFO] 31m 54s elapsed, 1/17 actions completed.
[WARNING] No actions completed for 15.0s, waiting on:
  - moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/login/login_store.dart
  - moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/login/widgets/background.dart
  - moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/login/account_picture.dart
  - moor_generator:moor_generator on lib/commom/widgets/custom_text_field.dart
  .. and 11 more
...
```

A mensagem apareceu repetidas vezes, como podem ver cerca de 30 minutos.

Procurei em alguns lugares a solução como:

1. https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/553
2. https://gitter.im/dart-lang/build?at=5eb9a3f820eaac18530279ba

E encontrei uma solução e gostaria de compartilhar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor solução mas funcionou para mim, no primeiro link que mencionei (https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/553) achei a seguinte receita de bolo (mas pode ser que não sirva para o seu caso, mas não custa tentar):

1. Feche todos os seus arquivos abertos (feche todas as abas de arquivos da sua IDE)
2. Execute o comando `flutter clean` no seu terminal
3. Execute o comando `flutter pub get` no seu terminal
4. Execute o comando `flutter packages upgrade` no seu terminal
5. Execute o comando `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` no seu terminal
6. Esse item não é necessário mas caso os passos anteriores não funcione, tente antes do "passo 1" adiciona o *package* `build_resolvers: ^1.3.10` no seu arquivo `pubspec.yaml` na seção `dev_dependencies`.

   Ficaria assim:

   ```
   dev_dependencies:
     flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter

     build_resolvers: ^1.3.10
     mobx_codegen: ^1.1.0+1
     build_runner: ^1.10.2
   ```

Como eu disse no início é algo que funcionou para mim e que pode não funcionar para você, quebrei bastante a cabeça até achar (mesmo sendo algo simples) mas espero que ajude quem estiver sofrendo com o mesmo erro.